# Did Captain America know Iron Man needs his arc reactor to live?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, iron-man, captain-america-civil-war

Towards the end of *Civil War*, Captain America:

> Starts smashing up Iron Man's Arc Reactor.

Doesn't he need that to live?

> Was Steve going for a kill shot, or did he not realise how important it was?

Comment: his arc tractor?

Comment: It's the west country version

Comment: Aside from his non-dependency (see answer below), the reactor was not completely smashed.  You can see some glow after it's damaged.  If it were completely destroyed, the suit would have zero power and Tony would have a hard time moving.

Comment: Point of note, the suit has it's own reactor.  That's the one that Captain smashed.

Comment: A better question would be "Why is it unshielded, exposed, and glowing to make it a conspicuous high value target?" and the answer is "Because it's a comic book."

Comment: I'm guessing by the votes and views this has gotten,  hardly anyone has seen Iron Man 3.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Oh, we've seen it. But only once. And then it was stricken from memory.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Tony hasn't needed the reactor to live ever since the end of Iron Man 3, when he underwent surgery to remove it. He doesn't wear it any more; now, the reactor is only for the suit.

> [we see Tony undergoing surgery to remove the shrapnel near his heart]
>
> **Tony Stark**: [voice over] Of course, there are people who say progress is dangerous. But I'll bet none of those idiots ever had to live with a chest full of shrapnel. And now...neither will I. Let me tell you, that was the best sleep I'd had in years.

It's likely Steve Rogers knew about this, since some time passed since Iron Man 3.

Comment: So one of the few MCU movies I've not seen is what I was missing.  Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't say you were "missing it", @AncientSwordRage.

Comment: IM3 accomplishes two things in the overall MCU.  1) It removes the need for the Arc Reactor implant, and 2) it sets the stage for Pepper and Tony splitting up.  Beyond that it doesn't really develop the universe at all, and the story-line is massively MEH.

Comment: 3) Introduces Extremis for Agents of Shield S1, 4) Develops the character of the President and the position of the US Government, 5) Develops the character of Tony Stark

Comment: Correct. 3), 4) and 5) are rather MEH.

Comment: Interestingly, there's a spot in Civil War where you can see the scar on Tony's chest where the reactor once was. I thought it was a nice touch.

Comment: 5.5) a teaser set after that movie using one of its characters establishes the existence of a much more powerful (probably mystical) bad guy

Comment: Didn't Agents of Shield introduce Extremis for IM3?

Comment: One other thing I liked about Iron Man 3 was that it established that Tony Stark is not a soldier, but had not entirely admitted it to himself. He's a thrillseeker, and someone who wants to help other people, but he developed massive PTSD and tried to keep pushing through it. You can see some of the difference in Avengers 2, where he's trying to find ways to use his technology without actually putting himself in harm's way. He's an engineer at heart, which contrasts with his Avengers teammates who are all trained or at least inclined to fight.

Comment: "where he's trying to find ways to use his technology without actually putting himself in harm's way" You know... like that time early in Avengers 2 where he get's out of his suit to explore the basement of the enemy's hideout. That kind of "without actually putting himself in harm's way."

Comment: @NKCampbell No.  [Iron Man III was released in April of 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_3), while Agents of SHIELD [came out in September, 2013.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agents_of_S.H.I.E.L.D.)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots that is interesting to note about Tony.  If we look at the progression I believe the suit was created around the core, and he used the suit in order to do what he had for revenge or whatnot in the first movie (it's been awhile).  Now that his tech has progressed he doesn't need to be in the suit, as shown in IM3.  There are others who also aren't fighters, for instance Dr. Bruce Banner turns into the Hulk, but he isn't all that in control of his powers all the time, and even when he is, he's such a powerhouse that I don't think it phases him, whereas a normal human will be hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Once the shrapnel was removed iron man didn't need it to live but only for the suit to function so therefore once he destroyed the reactor the suit shut down.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! While this answer is correct it does not seem to add any additional information to answers already given.

Comment: When did the shrapnel get removed?

Answer (score -2):

Its more that Capt America knew he needed it to function rather than to live. With the reactor damaged, he could beat Iron Man.

Comment: I get that he needs it to function,  but I didn't get that he didn't need it to live.

Answer (score -3):

I don't really think Cap knew that Tony removed the Arc Reactor. In the movie as you have seen, Cap does take a couple shots at the reactor which lead me to assume that Cap didn't know. And then again, Tony could have told Cap during the second Avengers movie. Also, reactor or not, Capt wouldn't have cared because when Tony started attacking Bucky, Cap just wanted to protect Bucky.